I can't find pytorch and cudnn version for CUDA 12.4. Which versions can I download and use?
nvidia-smi output says CUDA 12.4 as follows.

I downloaded and installed this as CUDA toolkit

and downloaded cudnn top one:

There is no selection for 12.4. Because of this i downloaded pytorch for CUDA 12.1.

I transferred cudnn files to CUDA folder. Bin folder added to path. And results:

I bought a computer to work with CUDA but I can't run it.

If you are using Pytorch, you don’t need to download any CUDA toolkit.  It ships with the minimal CUDA runtime components it requires. And by downloading CUDA 12.4, you have broken everything. Uninstall it

Can you confirm that the installed pytorch/CUDA versions are indeed the ones you provided? (pip list | grep torch). it might be that the installation led to the wrong version or even to a cpu compiled pytorch version

@Talonmiler According to my research, after installing CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN, PyTorch can be installed and used with GPU support. Am I wrong?

@talonmies So PyTorch doesn't support Cuda 12.4, even if you build PyTorch from source? 12.4 seems supported.

I have tried the solution @talonmies suggested (simply uninstall the Cuda toolkit v12.4) and run the command pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121 and it worked for me.
I hope this can help you in any way!

encountered your exact problem and found a solution.

I uninstalled both Cuda and Pytorch

Reinstalled Cuda 12.1:
here

Reinstalled latest version of PyTorch: here

Check if PyTorch was installed correctly: import torch x = torch.rand(5, 3) print(x)


The output should be something similar to:
tensor([[0.3380, 0.3845, 0.3217],
        [0.8337, 0.9050, 0.2650],
        [0.2979, 0.7141, 0.9069],
        [0.1449, 0.1132, 0.1375],
        [0.4675, 0.3947, 0.1426]])


Check if Cuda is enabled:
import torch if torch.cuda.is_available(): print("CUDA is available")


Good Luck!
